# How to scrape images from <img> and paste them into excel with proper placement/formatting?

Tags: excel, vba, python-requests, python-3.7, xlwings

### The process I want to automate:

Copy/paste formatted html tables and a sequence of Barcode gif's into Excel.

### Progress so far:

1. Able to scrape HTML tables and  tags
2. Able to paste HTML tables into Excel with proper formatting

My current solution is to scrape the html tables using requests/BeautifulSoup, copy html to the clipboard using pywin32, and then run a simple VBA macro to send the keys '^v' to past the html with formatting. This is the only way I've been able to get the html into Excel with formatting. The problem I ran into is that all the img tags are replaced by blank shapes. I've seen how to download images with requests, but I'm not sure how to get them into Excel with the proper placement. I explored generating the Barcode again with pyzbar, but there are several different types of 2D Barcodes and am not sure which I'm working with.

Example HTML snippet:

```html
<td>
<img src="barcodes/!asterisk.gif">
<img src="barcodes/X.gif">
<img src="barcodes/Y.gif">
<img src="barcodes/Z.gif">
<img src="barcodes/D.gif">
<img src="barcodes/H.gif">
<img src="barcodes/4.gif">
<img src="barcodes/8.gif">
<img src="barcodes/N.gif">
<img src="barcodes/6.gif">
<img src="barcodes/V.gif">
<img src="barcodes/!space.gif">
<img src="barcodes/1.gif">
<img src="barcodes/2.gif">
<img src="barcodes/0.gif">
<img src="barcodes/6.gif">
<img src="barcodes/0.gif">
<img src="barcodes/2.gif">
<img src="barcodes/!asterisk.gif">
</td>
```

Comment: Please share sample html tables with img tags you are scraping.

Comment: clipboard from msforms in vba will copy the table formatting allowing whole thing to be done in VBA. For images however, you will likely need the img srcs and to embed from those (matrix overlay positionally)